# while build net core 5.0 in docker show error "An error occurred while processing your request" (centos 8/VScode / Docker/EF Core)?

Tags: docker, entity-framework, asp.net-core, centos

When I create an ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio Code, then Add Docker support to the project , a Dockerfile is created which looks like this:

#Dockerfile #

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ENV BloggingDatabase="Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=myid;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=false;"
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8000

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MVCVue.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "MVCVue.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MVCVue.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MVCVue.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MVCVue.dll"]
```

I try to run it from Visual Studio Code can find the local database and connect to it. change database setting the environment variable run docker container， But when I run the app in the docker container cannot connect to the database the running  container it returns this error :

[image]

my Startup code

#Startup.cs#

```
namespace MVCVue
{

    public class Startup

    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)

        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<cpteContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")));

services.AddAntiforgery(opiton => {
    opiton.FormFieldName = "MyAntiForgeryField";
    opiton.HeaderName = "ANTI-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";

});

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())

            {

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            }

            else

            {

                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

                app.UseHsts();

            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();         
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>

            {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(

                    name: "default",

                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });

        }

    }

}
```

#appsettings.Development.json#

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=myid;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=false;"
  }

}
```

#DbContext#

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

        {

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()

                            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")

                           .Build();

            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)

            {

                var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase");

        
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            }

        }
```

#appsettings.json#

```
{

  "ConnectionStrings": {

    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=testdb;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=myid;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=false;"

  },



  "Logging": {

    "LogLevel": {

      "Default": "Information",

      "Microsoft": "Warning",

      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"

    }

  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*"

}
```

Comment: The error means that your program runs but has failed. Because you aren't running in development mode, the details of the error are hidden. The more detailed error messages are in the container logs. Look there.

Comment: I try to run it from Visual Studio Code can find the local database and connect to it. 
But when I run the app in the docker container cannot connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try code add-in dockerfile Environment variable after-show asp .net core error

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```